# New APK but don't update

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I was wondering if it was possible to update an APK in the Play Store but don't have my current users updated to the new release. I only want new users (or new download) to get the new APK. What would be the point in this? Suppose I discover a bug on signup method. I don't need my current users to have their applications updated, only new users...

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it works that way, but I guess the better solution is to test the signup process thoroughly before launching it. (May be install the apk on few devices). Second choice would be to use Beta testing in Google Play. Not sure if it works for your scenario.

Comment: Yes, but shit happens. Maybe the bug is not something visible to the user..